# How to uninstall broken installation of app musictube?

Tags: apps

i have LUMIA 532. i tried to install MUSICTUBE app from store. it showed that i downloaded it but when it comes to install it just an issue appears. now it is in list with apps but it has a message "be careful". how can i delete-uninstall this app or just to delete from the list of apps?

Comment: What version of Windows Phone (or Windows 10 Mobile) is your phone running? Have you tried long-pressing on the app and choosing "Uninstall"? Have you tried reinstalling it from the Store?

Comment: i have windows 8.1 because i think it will lag with 10.(with 8.1 and sd card is ultra fasst). it hasn't the choice of uninstal. when i go to reinstal it from store, there is no this choice. because i don't finish the procecdure of installation, i don\t know how to finish it, it's a loop. when i try to open the program from the list of programs, just it has the choice to repeat(the installation).   also the default direction of installation for apps is the phone memory